# How to write a stored proc that will join two tables and give the output

Tags: sql-server, join, stored-procedures

I am trying to write a SP that will join two tables and give the desired output.I am first creating a temporary table where i am listing all the fields of both tables and then trying to join the tables on the basis of a  join .But  it is not helping me. Here what i have done so far

```
  CREATE TABLE #es_jeet 
( 
   [txtype]          [CHAR](2) NULL, 
   [txdesc]          [VARCHAR](40) NULL, 
   [txrefno]         [CHAR](25) NULL, 
   [clntcode]        [CHAR](5) NULL, 
   [polno]           [CHAR](10) NULL, 
   [certno]          [CHAR](10) NULL, 
   [depcode]         [DECIMAL](5, 0) NULL, 
   [deptype]         [CHAR](1) NULL, 
   [namefirst]       [CHAR](50) NULL, 
   [namelast]        [CHAR](50) NULL, 
   [namemid]         [CHAR](2) NULL, 
   [inieffdt]        [DATETIME] NULL, 
   [status]          [CHAR](1) NULL, 
   [chgeffdt]        [DATETIME] NULL, 
   [suboffcode]      [CHAR](3) NULL, 
   [departcd]        [CHAR](6) NULL, 
   [memidno]         [CHAR](12) NULL, 
   [dob]             [DATETIME] NULL, 
   [sex]             [CHAR](1) NULL, 
   [marital]         [CHAR](1) NULL, 
   [occupation]      [CHAR](20) NULL, 
   [empno]           [CHAR](10) NULL, 
   [empdt]           [DATETIME] NULL, 
   [salary]          [DECIMAL](13, 2) NULL, 
   [bankac]          [CHAR](40) NULL, 
   [memnation]       [CHAR](3) NULL, 
   [effdate]         [DATETIME] NULL, 
   [bankcode]        [CHAR](4) NULL, 
   [salarymode]      [CHAR](1) NULL, 
   [bankactype]      [CHAR](1) NULL, 
   [bankaceffdate]   [DATETIME] NULL, 
   [bankacstatus]    [CHAR](1) NULL, 
   [firstcovdt]      [DATETIME] NULL, 
   [maxageexemptind] [CHAR](1) NULL, 
   [vipstatus]       [CHAR](1) NULL, 
   [sponsoridno]     [VARCHAR](20) NULL, 
   [passportno]      [CHAR](15) NULL, 
   [nationalidno]    [CHAR](30) NULL, 
   [bankname]        [CHAR](40) NULL, 
   [branchname]      [CHAR](40) NULL, 
   [branchaddress]   [CHAR](40) NULL, 
   [bankcurrency]    [CHAR](3) NULL, 
   [swiftcode]       [CHAR](15) NULL, 
   [servicedeskid]   [CHAR](10) NULL, 
   [servicedeskdate] [DATETIME] NULL, 
   [dmpindicator]    [CHAR](1) NULL, 
   [salarychgeffdt]  [DATETIME] NULL, 
   [studentind]      [CHAR](1) NULL, 
   [outcntyind]      [CHAR](1) NULL, 
   [prodcode]        [CHAR](5) NULL, 
   [benplncd]        [CHAR](3) NULL, 
   [covgcode]        [CHAR](5) NULL, 
   [proposedsa]      [DECIMAL](11, 0) NULL, 
   [prdstatus]       [CHAR](1) NULL, 
   [benid]           [CHAR](20) NULL, 
   [benname]         [CHAR](40) NULL, 
   [benrelat]        [CHAR](15) NULL, 
   [beneffdt]        [DATETIME] NULL, 
   [benshare]        [DECIMAL](5, 4) NULL, 
   [remark]          [CHAR](16) NULL, 
   [rcdsts]          [CHAR](1) NULL, 
   [rcdusrid]        [CHAR](20) NULL, 
   [rcddtstmp]       [DATETIME] NULL, 
   [txstatus]        [CHAR](1) NULL, 
   [uploadusrid]     [VARCHAR](20) NULL, 
   [uploadtime]      [DATETIME] NULL, 
   [errorcode]       [CHAR](6) NULL, 
   [errormsg]        [VARCHAR](100) NULL, 
   [isprocessing]    [CHAR](1) NULL, 
   [SPONSORTYPE]    [INT] NULL  ,
   [GROSSSALARYRANGE][CHAR](1) NULL,
   [SALARYBASEDONCOMMISSION][CHAR](3) NULL,
   [RESIDINGEMIRATE][CHAR](20) NULL,
   [RESIDINGLOCATION][CHAR](20) NULL,
   [WORKLOCATIONEMIRATE][CHAR](20) NULL,
   [WORKLOCATION][CHAR](20) NULL,
   [MEMBERINSURANCEINSIXMONTH][CHAR](50) NULL,
   [VISASPONSORID][CHAR](20) NULL,
   [SPONSORCONTACTNUMBER][CHAR](50) NULL,
   [SPONSOREMAILID][CHAR](50) NULL

  )
  INSERT INTO  #es_jeet

    SELECT DISTINCT A.txtype,X.txdesc,txrefno,A.clntcode,A.polno,A.certno,A.depcode,deptype,namefirst,namelast,
            namemid,A.inieffdt,A.status,A.chgeffdt,suboffcode,departcd,memidno,dob,sex,marital,occupation,empno, 
            empdt,salary,A.bankac,memnation,A.effdate,A.bankcode,A.salarymode,bankactype,bankaceffdate,bankacstatus, 
            firstcovdt,maxageexemptind,vipstatus,sponsoridno,passportno,nationalidno,bankname,branchname,branchaddress, 
            bankcurrency,swiftcode,servicedeskid,servicedeskdate,dmpindicator,salarychgeffdt,studentind, outcntyind,
            PRODCODE =NULL,BENPLNCD =NULL,COVGCODE =NULL,PROPOSEDSA =NULL,PRDSTATUS =NULL,BENID = NULL,BENNAME =NULL, 
            BENRELAT =NULL,BENEFFDT =NULL,BENSHARE = NULL,REMARK =NULL,A.rcdsts,A.rcdusrid,A.rcddtstmp,txstatus,uploadusrid, 
            uploadtime,errorcode,errormsg, isprocessing ,TR.SPONSORTYPE,TR.GROSSSALARYRANGE,TR.SALARYBASEDONCOMMISSION,
            TR.RESIDINGEMIRATE,TR.RESIDINGLOCATION,TR.WORKLOCATIONEMIRATE,TR.WORKLOCATION,TR.MEMBERINSURANCEINSIXMONTH,
            TR.VISASPONSORID,TR.SPONSORCONTACTNUMBER,TR.SPONSOREMAILID

                    FROM            
                   tmemtrans A  (NOLOCK)
                   INNER JOIN es_txtypes X  (NOLOCK)
                           ON A.txtype = X.txtype 
                   INNER JOIN tpolicy P  (NOLOCK)
                           ON A.polno = P.polno 
                   INNER JOIN tpolpdt TP (nolock) 
                           ON A.polno = tp.polno         
                   INNER JOIN TMEMBERREGULATORYINFO TR (nolock)
                          ON TR.CLNTCODE = A.CLNTCODE
                          AND TR.CERTNO = A.CERTNO
                          AND TR.DEPCODE = A.DEPCODE
        WHERE  A.rcdsts = 'A'
```

so here #es_jeet is a temporary table where i am listing all the fields and i am joining al these tables to get the result.Please help

Comment: That looks ok.  What's the problem that you're seeing?

Comment: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 122
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'INSERT'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 132
Incorrect syntax near '.'.

Comment: You have not closed the CREATE TABLE bracket, and the last column of the CREATE has a comma after it.

Comment: @dsolimano i have pasted the output can you please help

Comment: @GinjaNinja the backet is there in the last line .can you please edit my code??

Comment: @JeetChatterjee: The closing bracket should be after the CREATE TABLE (cols...), not after the INSERT.  I suspect that the issue you have is a typo, hence me editing your code above would not help to find the issue - please [paste the code as you have it

Comment: @GinjaNinja edited my post please see still getting that error

Comment: You should take a look at this article before you continue littering your database with NOLOCK hints. http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/ At the very least you should include the WITH keyword as omitting it is deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

1. Remove the `,` from the end of `[SPONSOREMAILID][CHAR](50) NULL,` and put a `)`
2. Add a `,` at the end of the line `uploadtime,errorcode,errormsg, isprocessing ,TR.SPONSORTYPE,TR.GROSSSALARYRANGE,TR.SALARYBASEDONCOMMISSION`

Comment: @Diamond Geezer i have edited according to you but still getting same issue

Comment: You're also missing a`,` at the end of the line `uploadtime,errorcode,errormsg, isprocessing ,TR.SPONSORTYPE,TR.GROSSSALARYRANGE,TR.SALARYBASEDONCOMMISSION`. I have updated my answer to show include this.

Comment: @Diamond Geezer are you telling me to add  a comma after TR.SPONSOREMAILID ??? i have done that

Comment: @Diamond Geezar that error have gone but i am getting Insert Error: Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.

Comment: That means that the number of columns in the SELECT list is different to the number of columns in your table.

Comment: @Diamond Geezer  I have matched the  fields of the table to the select statment .i  have edited my post

Comment: And do you still get an error?

Comment: @Diamond Geezer yes sir still getting that error

Comment: @Diamond Geezer tell me one thing that which tables i have selected should i include all their values to the temp table ??

Comment: Why are you using a temporary table anyway? You could just use a `SELECT` statement.